# take image of full datagrid

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, silverlight-4.0

I have:

```
<Grid>
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>

 <sdk:DataGrid Grid.Row="0" ...>
 ...
 </sdk:DataGrid>

</Grid>
```

Note there is no `Height="Auto"` in row definition so that datagrid takes all height.
I'm trying to make a picture of **full** datagrid (include invisible space that needs scrolling). I tried:

```
ImageExtensions.ToImage(myDataGrid);
```

also

```
var writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(pixelWidth, pixelHeight);
```

where pixelHeight was obtained either using SizeChanged event or DesiredSize property.

All in vain. Height was always the height of screen. If I used auto="height" in row definition then it would work, but datagrid wouldn't take all space / or no scroller when it's too large.

Anyone managed to get it work?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround:

```
GridLength h = grid.RowDefinitions[0].Height;

grid.RowDefinitions[0].Height = GridLength.Auto;
grid.UpdateLayout();


try
{
    var writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)myDataGrid.ActualWidth, (int)myDataGrid.ActualHeight);
}
finally
{
    grid.RowDefinitions[0].Height = h;
    grid.UpdateLayout();
}
```